# When to use CSS + sign

Tags: html, css

Very easy question. I have been using CSS for a while but rarely use + sigh for my code. Could any one explain what the best time is to use it? I couldn't find anything from Google...Thanks a millions...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found that *adjacent sibling selectors* are useful when you want to apply special styling to the first element of a series of elements.  For example, if you want to style the first paragraph of an article differently from the rest, you could use:

```
p {
    /* styles for the first paragraph  */
}

p + p {
    /* styles for all other paragraphs */
}
```

This can replace using `class="first"` in many situations.

**EDIT:** Using the `first-child` pseudo-class would work better for this specific case, since it's supported by a wider range of browsers. (Thanks alex)

You might also want to adjust how certain elements are positioned when next to each other.  If you have an unordered list that looks fine on its own, but needs less padding at the top when it's next to a paragraph, you could use:

```
ul {
    padding-top: 1em;
    /* Default ul styling */
}

p + ul {
    padding-top: 0;
    /* special styling for lists that come after paragraphs */
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, it actually answers the question (when is the best case).

Comment: Is the first example not the same as `p:first-child { }` and the cascading effect?

Comment: @alex - Yeah, you're right.  `first-child` would actually work better for cross-browser reasons. I just always forget it exists. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. It has better support than `:last-child` for the time being too.

Comment: `p:first-child` is _not_ going to work as well as, say `h2 + p` though in case you happen to be putting any element, such as a heading, before the `p` you're targeting.

Answer (score 6):

Use it whenever you want to target the next matching selector of a certain selector. E.g.

```
<p>Item 1</p>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
<p>Item 4</p>
```

Using `p + div` will allow for you to style *Item 2*, since it's right after a `p` tag. [Example in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/ngeJW/)

Using `p + p` will not style anything, since the next `p` tag isn't right next to the first one. [Example in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/g6aSs/)

Using `div + p` will allow for you to style *Item 4*, since it's right after a `div`. [Example in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/LcHcZ/)

And so on...

Comment: Very simple explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

It is the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the
>   following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is
>   the subject of the selector. The
>   selector matches if E1 and E2 share
>   the same parent in the document tree
>   and E1 immediately precedes E2,
>   ignoring non-element nodes (such as
>   text nodes and comments).

In less generic terms, it lets you select an element like normal, but to also qualify that it has a particular element before it at the same level.

For instance with this HTML:

```
<p><div></div></p>
<span></span>
```

You could normally select the `span` by just asking for `span`, but if you only want to affect the `span` with a certain style when there is a `p` just before it you can use `p + span`.  Note, you can't use `div + span` here because `div` is at a different "level".

Answer (score 3):

> Also added in CSS2 was the direct
>   adjacent combinator. For example,
>   imagine you want to indent all
>   paragraphs in a document except for
>   ones immediately following a
>   sub-heading (`<h2>`). The second rule
>   below shows an `h2` selector combined
>   with a p selector using a plus sign as
>   the combinator to indicate that the
>   declaration applies only if `p`
>   immediately follows `h2`:
>
> ```
> p { text-indent: 0.5in; }
> h2 + p { text-indent: 0; }
> ```

From - http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/18/css3-selectors.html